# Using Directory.Move to rename a folder is leaving the old folder behind and unable to be found to be deleted(UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have a folder I'm trying to rename (I read i should use Directory.move to do this).

"ExampleA"

I use Directory.Move("ExampleA","New Folder") (code below)

Where "New Folder" is what "ExampleA" Should be renamed to, this works, it moves the directory and it's contents but it's also leaving the "ExampleA" folder still there, and when i try and delete it it says It Doesn't exist.

Full Code here

```
string oldDirectory = Application.dataPath + "/Photos/" + GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent<CameraController>().cardNames[assignmentButton];
    Directory.Move(oldDirectory, Application.dataPath + "/Photos/" + renameInput.text);
    Debug.Log("Attempting to delete: " + oldDirectory);
    if(Directory.Exists(oldDirectory))
        Directory.Delete(oldDirectory,true);
```

The old directory does indeed exist, but this code seems to think it doesn't, i get thrown an error saying it doesn't exist if i remove the Directory.Exists check.

Comment: Well there’s a bunch of reasons but usually move does just that the delete would be unnecessary. However. The empty folder can be left depending on OS id the folder is in use or your av blocks it for similar reasons

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to happen in a built unity project, it works completely as intended. My guess is that there's an issue with File.
Delete working in the unity directory or that my unity directory is currently in a Github folder which may limit my use of deleting files.
So because of this, I'll class this as answered.